# Are there any books which reduce famous Philosophical Arguments to Logical Notation?

Tags: logic

I have just started studying logic and wish to find some example arguments by famous philosophers broken down very plainly into their premises and conclusions, along with the logical notation to the argument.

Comment: See [Gödel's Ontological Argument](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ontological-arguments/#GodOntArg) and [Gödel's ontological proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_ontological_proof): with logical notation, but not "plain".

Comment: I'm coincidentally looking for something similar. I've found there's a lot of trickiness to this process "translating a famous philosophical argument to formal logic", c.f., chapter 4 of Catarina Dutilh Novaes' _Formalizing Medieval Logical Theories_.

Comment: Oh, and a good [preprint](http://m-phi.blogspot.com/2011/11/formal-methods-and-history-of.html) on formal methods in the history of philosophy.

Comment: Bryan Hall, et al., have written [The Arguments of Kant's _Critique of Pure Reason_](http://www.amazon.com/Arguments-Kants-Critique-Pure-Reason/dp/073914166X) which attempts to formalize a good portion of the book, but only at the level of propositional logic as opposed to a full-blown first-order logic translation.

Answer (score 3):

1) The famous logician Kurt Goedel left behind a formalized "proof" for the ontological argument of Anselm of Canterbury.

Anselm gave a "proof" that the term "a being than which none greater can be conceived" must refer to some existing being, i.e., that there must exist a being than which none greater can be conceived.

See the following lecture by the logician Brendel for a formalization of Goedels "proof"

http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/logik/Veranstaltungen/cl2010/slides/brendel.pdf

It closes with a critical assessment of what Goedel's formalization proves and what it does not prove.

2) You may also read Gettier's presentation of the "Gettier example" in

http://www.ditext.com/gettier/gettier.html

The Gettier example is considered a counter-example against a widely hold definition of knowlegde as justified true belief. Gettier's formalization is not so extensive like Goedel's argument.

Answer (score 2):

Some parts of Wittgenstein's "Tractatus Logical-Philosophicus" are written in purely logical notation and Wittgenstein's view at the time (he moved away from it later) was called logical atomism: he wanted to break down all meaningful statements into basic atomic logical sentences. Bertrand Russell was also a proponent of this view. See Russell's famous "the present present king of France" example.

Comment: W's [Tractatus](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/#TLP) is "about" logic, but I think that it has **no** examples of "famous Philosophical Argument reduced to Logical Notation".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA studying Wittgenstein's and Russell's logical atomism would help the op learn how to achieve this for philosophical statements in general.

Answer (score 1):

John Hospers's *Introduction to Philosophical Analysis* was written as an introductory textbook, with a strong emphasis on providing logical analyses of important arguments. [link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CDUXWMS)

There's also a book called *Just the Arguments* which I think provides nice little argument analyses from the great philosophers. [link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005K04HLS)

I haven't used either text myself, so I can't vouch for the quality, but they seem to fit the description you're looking for.